# Load local html on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have in my server `.html` page located on `c:\test\test.html`.

I want to display `test.html` inside iframe on the client machine, how can I do that?

What I tried:

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="file:///c:\test\test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
```

But it's found the `test.html` file on the client machine, so how can I make that the `test.html` will be loaded from the server?

If it isn't possible, how can I do that in another way?

Comment: You can't load local files from your computer through the server. You should upload the test file to your server to and then load this file in an iframe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you have the page on your *server* you need to use an `http://` url, not `file:///`. It's a little tricky because the web server has a [different syntax](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths) for file paths than your file system. Here are some options.

---

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="./test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
```

You can use these if `test.html` is in the **same directory** as your main-page.  (The main-page is the html with the iframe in it.)

---

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="../test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
```

You can use this if `test.html` is in the **parent directory** of your main-page, as long as it doesn't go beyond the web server's "root" directory.

---

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="../test/test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
```

You can use this if the `test.html` is in the **sibling directory** of your main-page, such as `path/views/test/test.html` when your main-page is `path/views/main/page.html`.

---

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="https://www.server.com/test/test.html" width="1000" height="1000"  frameborder="0">
```

Or, you can always use an [absolute path](https://www.webstix.com/knowledgebase/general/relative-links-vs-absolute-links), based on the complete url of your `test.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to place "test.html" file the public directory on the server. Or else make "test" directory publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use server side language like PHP, ASP.NET, node.js etc and create a "proxy", that will get the desired file as parameter, read the file on the server, and send its contents.

For example, in ASP.NET you can have such code:

**Download.aspx**

```cs
<script language="C#" runat="server">
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
    {
        Label1.Text = "Missing or invalid ID";
        return;
    }

    string filePath = "";
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            filePath = "c:\\test\\test.html";
            break;
    }

    if (filePath.Length == 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "ID " + id + " does not exist";
        return;
    }

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Label1.Text = "Requested file '" + filePath + "' does not exist";
        return;
    }

    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then have such iframe:

```
<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="Download.aspx?id=1" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load from your PC like c:... You only can load file, from your server. If this html file, and test.html file is in a same directory on your server, easily load with test.html, if it is in another directory, then use the directory name like, test/test.html

Comment: This answer is technically correct. Although, some parts such as *If this html, file and test.html file is in a same directory on your server, easily load with test.html* are not clear. Do edit your answer so that it better explains what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

html iframe element cannot load an empty webpage (no text or images on the body element).

I mistakenly used an empty webpage, it was not loading. the comment above help me to fix it.

Comment: Is this commentary on another post? Doesn't seem to warrant its own answer

Comment: Which of the existing comments (I am pretty sure you mean an answer) is it which you are saying thanks for? Note that there is no "above" on StackOverflow, because the order of displayed posts is individually configurable. For me for example, your post is at the top. Also, if this is indeed only "Thanks" you should delete it, because it is not considered an answer on StackOverflow. If you to mean to contribute an answer, please [eidt] according to [answer].