# How to load html file into iframe element in React?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I want to load a local html file into an **iframe** element in React. I followed the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393063/load-local-html-on-iframe), but it doesn't work.

The folder structure in my project is like below:

- src

  - components

    - myIframeComponent.js
  - testHTMLFiles

    - index.html

Iframe element looks like this:

```
 <iframe
   src="../testHTMLFiles/index.html"
   height="100%"
   width="100%"
   frameBorder="0"
 />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you solve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

The iframe src must contain an absolute url:

```
https://www.example.com/testHTMLFiles/index.html
```

This is because in your build the file is not avaliable at this position after build and iframe path is resolved as iframe is instanced.

Comment: src="www.example.com/testHTMLFiles/index.html" will work

Comment: http is not necessary, you can use also relative paths, absolute url (with or without http) is necessary if you build without configuring properly webpack

Comment: Is local host an exception? I tried src="https:// www.localhost:3000/testHTMLFiles/index.html" but doesn't work.

Comment: in your build folder do you have such subfolder ?

Comment: I use create-react-app and "npm start", I haven't used "npm run build" yet. So I dont't have any build folder.

Comment: Under the hood webpack is making a dev build, anyway, you must be able to reach it from your browser address bar. If you are able to do so, your iframe will be too.

Comment: https://www.example.com/testHTMLFiles/index.html this is considered as route to testHTMLFiles/index. How does it load as html?