# How to render an iframe of local page within React app using React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-router-dom

I'm creating a React JS serverless app based on [this](https://github.com/bloomui/tokyo-free-black-react-admin-dashboard-js) template, inside a page I need to include an iframe to render an HTML file.

The iframe should has a source like `./public/myfolder/index.html` (as you can see from "Structure" below).

The problem is that the iframe render a 404 page instead, I think it's because of my routes configuration (as here below).

Structure:

```
/public
 /myfolder
  index.html //src for the iframe

/src
 App.js
 router.js
 /content
  /overview
   index.js //iframe page
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './router';
import ThemeProvider from './theme/ThemeProvider';

const App = () => {

    const content = useRoutes(routes);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
        { content }
        < /ThemeProvider>
    );
}
export default App;
```

I don't know how to declare the HTML page path inside React Router Dom.

**Router.js**

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import BaseLayout from 'src/layouts/BaseLayout';

const Overview = Loader(lazy(() => import('src/content/overview')));

const Status404 = Loader(lazy(() => import('src/content/pages/Status/Status404')));

const routes = [
    {
        path: '*',
        element: <BaseLayout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                element: <Overview />
            },
            {
                path: 'overview',
                element: (
                    <Navigate
                        to="/"
                        replace
                    />
                )
            },
            {
                path: 'status',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '/',
                        element: (
                            <Navigate
                                to="404"
                                replace
                            />
                        )
                    },
                    {
                        path: '404',
                        element: <Status404 />
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '*',
                element: <Status404 />
            },
        ]
    },
];

export default routes;
```

**Baselayout**

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const BaseLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return <>{children || <Outlet />}</>;
};

export default BaseLayout;
```

Now, inside my react page "Overview", I tried an iframe like this:

```
<iframe
    id="myIframe"
    src="./myfolder/index.html"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    frameBorder="0"
    title="myIframe"
/>
```

But the inner iframe shows me a 404 page.

I tried also:

```
src="./public/myfolder/index.html" 

src="http://localhost:3000/public/myfolder/index.html"
```

Nothing work. How can I change my routes to render my iframe element correctly?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393654/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese no, I saw it before and since react-router-dom redirects all my paths, it's not working...main page is in ./src/app/etc ... folder and HTML is in ./public/myfolder/index.html

Comment: Is not `"./myfolder/index.html"` the html file you are trying to load in the `iframe` though? I fail to see how any routing/navigation in the current page/app has anything to do with the html you are loading in an `iframe`. What am I missing here? What do you mean by "`react-router-dom` redirects all my paths"?

Comment: @DrewReese from my react page, located in `./src/content/overview` I tried to insert an iframe as above in my question. So if I try with `src="./myfolder/index.html"` it results in a 404 page, even if my HTML page is correctly inside `./public/myfolder/index.html` ...I thought it was because of my routes configuration, since any call from other pages that are not defined paths returns in a 404 page.

Comment: A 404 page where? In the `iframe`? From the html file running in the `iframe`? A 404 page in your app? Maybe it will help to include all relevant code for what you are trying to do. Can you add the `public/myFolder/index.html` file to your question?

Comment: @DrewReese the 404 is only inside the iframe element, the Overview react page has nothing wrong...and `public/myFolder/index.html` is a simple html file like `<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>` and I can view it normally from my web browser directly.

Comment: FWIW I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe with your code in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-render-an-iframe-of-local-page-within-react-app-using-react-router-dom-rv2dhq) as I understand it.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks a lot! After comment out `path: '*'` in `routes`, using `http://localhost:3000/myfolder/index.html` in my iframe as source works...however, I don't understand why I can't use an absolute path instead of that URL. :/

Comment: I don't know the specifics, other than it it's how nested routes are built up using relative paths... ‍♂️  I just fixed all the RRD warnings that popped up from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `Router` -> `routes` you have to remove this line: `path: '*'`.

Then you have to try again one solution between relative path and url:

```
src="./myfolder/index.html" 

src="http://localhost:3000/myfolder/index.html"
```